# Encrypting a text using pem public certificate not working

Tags: java, ssl, cryptography, certificate, pem

I am actually using java codes to encrypt a sample text using a public certificate which is of type pem. When encrypting I keep getting the following error :

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
> at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:239)
> at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:352)
> at TextEncryptor.getPublicKeyFromString(TextEncryptor.java:45)
> at TextEncryptor.main(TextEncryptor.java:19)
> Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
> at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:396)
> at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:401)
> at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:122)
> at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:330)
> at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:235)
> ... 3 more

Here is the code I'm using  :

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.util.Base64;

public class TextEncryptor {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Replace with the path to your public key (.crt) file
        String publicKeyPath = "PublicKey.crt";

        // Load public key from file
        String publicKeyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(publicKeyPath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKeyFromString(publicKeyContent);

        // Text to be encrypted
        String plaintext = "Hello, this is a secret message.";

        // Encrypt the text
        String encryptedText = encryptText(plaintext, publicKey);

        System.out.println("Original text: " + plaintext);
        System.out.println("Encrypted text: " + encryptedText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Method to load a public key from a string
private static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws Exception {
    //remove the begin and end
    //System.out.println("crt file : " + key);
    String publicKeyPEM = key
    .replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "")
    .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
    .replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "");
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPEM);
    X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
}

// Method to encrypt text using a public key
private static String encryptText(String plaintext, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
}
```

}

The public certificate is like this :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MI......................==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

(I skipped some content from the certificate to keep only header and footer here)

What am I missing here ?